# fire onload event when open a DIV page inside android phonegap application

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

i am trying to activate a alert message inside my android application which will open when i open a specific div called `page2` , however all my tries went unsuccessful , each time the application run , it display the message without opening the div itself.

here is my code

My Div code

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two2</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried to Jquery to onload the alert message , here is the code :

```
$('#page2').load('', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

i put the jQuery script inside the div, did not work , then on the header but the same problem remains

any suggestions ?

Comment: How does #page2 actually get shown?  You can't use the load event because you're not loading anything into it.

Answer (score 1):

If your listening for page changes:

```
$('page2').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```